# how prevent data capture in a login page installed in various sites

Tags: php, forms, security, authentication

I developed a login form (in php and also .net) to authenticate a user against a centralized database. I passed this form to several customers, to have it included in their respective sites. Upon correct authentication, the user is redirected, based in the customer that had the form installed. All is working good, however I have a concern: How can I prevent the customers that installed my form, to modify it to capture the users' credentials? The customer can simply insert a javascript function that store the credentials, and then continue with the auth flow. In other words: what measures can I use to assure that the customers never know what are the user's login/pass? (The form must reside in each customers' site, it's impossible to me to host it anywhere)

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to have your script redirect the users to your site and have them login there. Once logged in, you redirect the user back to your script install on your customers site. When you do the redirect back, you will include a token as a GET param. Your script on the customers site then uses that token you to call a web page/service in your system to get the user details.

This will allow the script on your customers side to have no knowledge of any kind of password, user or database.

Comment: Thanks Sam, so you think the only solution is remove the "login" functionality from the form, and use a link to a external form? The only problem is that I cannot host this form in a centralized site, and also I must know from which customer site the user is authenticating...

Comment: @user312305 If the from is on there server there is not way to stop your clients from taking the data. You can solve the issue if knowing which client it is when you give them the form to put on their server you can add a variable to indicate who it is coming from. I guess with the central database I assumed you had a central web server too.